# c# stream reader reading text file into richtextbox inbetween [] tags

Tags: c#, text, stream

I have a text file that i want to read into a richtextbox on my form using a button 
      Here is the text file:
       [1]
     Hello this is a text file. I am reading this into a richtextbox. 
I want multiple rows into the textbox to display on one button click. 
      [/1]

Here is my code:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"F:\test.txt"))
    {
        bool content = false;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (line.Contains("[1]"))
            {
                content = true;
            }

            if (content == true)
            {
                txtContent.AppendText(reader.ReadLine());
            }

            if (line.Contains("[/1]"))
            {
                content = false;
                break;
                //txtContent.AppendText(reader.ReadLine());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When i click button2 it only adds the first line

how can i read all the text in between [1]  and  [/1]

I have looked into the use of XML but my text file will have alot of data in by the end so ive tried to avoid using it. 
I would like to then go onto using the same richtextbox to store text inbetween [2] and [/2] on another button click

Thanks for your help

Comment: You need a *bool* variable.  Set it to *true* when you recognize [1], to *false* when you recognize [/1].  If it is true then append the line of text.

Comment: @HansPassant i have tried your suggestion and i am getting the same problem, How would i set up this variable properly? i am struggling to grasp it i have amended my code to show my attempt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic looks like it may skips lines.

You read a line in from the file and if it contains [1] you set your flag.  Then you check if your flag is set and read another line from the file.  So this won't include the previously read line.  Then you check if that next line contains[/1] and break from your reading loop.

Say you read your first line and its "[1]Hello this is a text file." Your logic will not include "Hello this is a text file" in the RichTextBox, because you've requested the next line to be read.  Then you check for your end tag ([/1]), which would result in false.  Now we come back to the top of the loop and read the next line ("I am reading this into a richtextbox.").  This will fail your first check, and your content flag is still true so now this current line will not be added to the RichTextBox because we did another ReadLine().

Now your question is stated like the beginning tag ([1]) is on a line by itself.  If that's true, then just continue your loop after you set the content flag to true.

If you don't want your tags [1] and [/1] to not be in the RichTextBox then Replace them in the line variable and add the line variable to your RichTextBox.  Don't read another line to add to your RichTextBox, just use the line you already read in if it meets your condition of being between your tags.

This snippet should handle all (generic formats) of your file, unless your tags appear again within your tags (For example, "[1][1][/1][/1]")

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (@"F:\test.txt"))
     {
         bool content = false; 
         while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
         {
            if (line.Contains("[1]"))
            {
                content = true;
                // You only need this continue if this is on a line by itself
                continue;
            }
            if (content == true)
            {
                // The Replace should remove your tags and add what's left to the RichTextBox
                txtContent.AppendText(line.Replace("[1]", "").Replace("[/1]", ""));
            }
            if(line.Contains("[/1]"))
            {
                content = false;
                break; 
            }
        }
    }
}
```